# python - exclude text from a string

Tags: python, string, time

I have a separate system that is exporting to AVExprt.txt.
In that export it has TIME combined (no space) AM/PM.
How can I exclude the AM/PM from the time?

```
def main():

    import linecache
    filename='AVExprt.txt' 
    appendfile='AVExprt_Main.txt'
    date=linecache.getline(filename,2) 
    remove_lines= 5 

    with open(filename,'r') as file_object:
        lines = file_object.readlines()
        for i in range(remove_lines):
            del lines[0]

    with open(appendfile,'a') as file_object:   
        for line in lines:
            line = date.rstrip() + "," + line
            file_object.write(line)

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show sample data from the file AVExprt.txt

Comment: Depending of the format, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime ; but showing us an example would be really helpful

Comment: Replace it with nothing: `string = string.replace('AM','')`

Comment: Here is an example of text:
"Doe, John","8675309","",9:22PM,"",6:59AM,"12/27/2018"

When I import into Power Pivot Excel will not read it in time format.